# How to uninstall outpost firewall pro driver?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I want to reinstall outpost firewall pro but encounter "setup has detected that outpost firewall pro drivers are still present in system. Please uninstall previous version, reboot, and run setup again.". How to uninstall outpost firewall pro driver?

[image: reinstall outpost firewall pro encounter error]

Comment: You will have to manually find the drivers on your system and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [**clean.exe**](http://www.agnitum.com/support/kb/article.php?id=1000159) utility and run it in **Safe Mode** as detailed on that page to clear out all traces of the program from your PC.